# Solr prefix query with ISOLatin1Accent characters

Tags: solr

I'm trying to index a field in a way that allows me to find the document using prefix query '`æb*`' as well as '`aeb*`'. What happens: it finds the latter, but not the former. Same issue with å, î, etc.

This is my schema:

```
<fieldtype name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

As you can see I'm using the same analyzers for index and query. So If I understand correctly, the query '`æb*`' should get normalized to '`aeb*`'. Is the '`*`' symbol somehow interfering? How can I set up my schema for the desired results?

I'm using Solr 1.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On prefix, wildcard and fuzzy searches, no text analysis is performed on the search word.
So even if the MappingCharFilterFactory is specified at search time, the search term won't undergo any analysis.
And as the analysis is applied at index time, it will only match `aeb*` (accent filter and lowercased), not even any [upper case matches](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2438).

You can either define your own query parser and analyze the search terms for prefix query.
Else, define fields with accented and non accented versions, and have search work on both.
However, you still need to lower case your search terms.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will either normalize it on my end before indexing, or just drop normalization entirely.